# how can I fix gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS to install bwa

Tags: macos, unix, alignment

I am trying to install bwa package in the terminal of mac. I downloaded bwa-0.7.17 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/bio-bwa/files/

I followed the steps to install it but when I tried to "make", it showed me this:

gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  utils.c -o utils.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  kthread.c -o kthread.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  kstring.c -o kstring.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  ksw.c -o ksw.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwt.c -o bwt.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bntseq.c -o bntseq.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwa.c -o bwa.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwamem.c -o bwamem.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwamem_pair.c -o bwamem_pair.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwamem_extra.c -o bwamem_extra.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  malloc_wrap.c -o malloc_wrap.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  QSufSort.c -o QSufSort.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwt_gen.c -o bwt_gen.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  rope.c -o rope.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  rle.c -o rle.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  is.c -o is.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwtindex.c -o bwtindex.o
ar -csru libbwa.a utils.o kthread.o kstring.o ksw.o bwt.o bntseq.o bwa.o bwamem.o bwamem_pair.o bwamem_extra.o malloc_wrap.o QSufSort.o bwt_gen.o rope.o rle.o is.o bwtindex.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwashm.c -o bwashm.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwase.c -o bwase.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwaseqio.c -o bwaseqio.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwtgap.c -o bwtgap.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwtaln.c -o bwtaln.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bamlite.c -o bamlite.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwape.c -o bwape.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  kopen.c -o kopen.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  pemerge.c -o pemerge.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  maxk.c -o maxk.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwtsw2_core.c -o bwtsw2_core.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwtsw2_main.c -o bwtsw2_main.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwtsw2_aux.c -o bwtsw2_aux.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwt_lite.c -o bwt_lite.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwtsw2_chain.c -o bwtsw2_chain.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  fastmap.c -o fastmap.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  bwtsw2_pair.c -o bwtsw2_pair.o
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  main.c -o main.o
gcc -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS bwashm.o bwase.o bwaseqio.o bwtgap.o bwtaln.o bamlite.o bwape.o kopen.o pemerge.o maxk.o bwtsw2_core.o bwtsw2_main.o bwtsw2_aux.o bwt_lite.o bwtsw2_chain.o fastmap.o bwtsw2_pair.o main.o -o bwa -L. -lbwa -lm -lz -lpthread

Then I tried again "make" and it showed:

make: Nothing to be done for `all'

Do you know what is the problem and how can I fix it? I would really appreciate your help.

All the best,

Mayra

Comment: Perhaps you should try the alternative route of [installing homebrew](https://brew.sh) and then running `brew install bwa` which should pull the [same version of bio-bwa from github](https://github.com/lh3/bwa). Note that I haven't tried this specific installation, however.

Comment: I did it. It works!! Thank you so much!!!